# Use bootstrap dynamic modal for delete confirmation (laravel blade)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

My goal is to use bootstrap modal as delete confirmation. But the problem is I need to transfer a *dynamic variable* (which contains item ID) value to bootstrap modal for submit post request to delete that specific item.
Please check Modal Part where `value="foo"` is set now tell me how can I make this "foo" as dynamic variable which will be coming from **laravel** blade template part ("`<td><a href="{{'#'}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a></td>`")
Whats the solution? I prefer `javascript` solution.

#### Bootstrap Modal Part

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete_dividend" value="foo">Delete</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### Laravel Blade Template Part

```
@foreach($dividends_10 as $_dividend_data)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{Portfolio\StockModel::select('short_name')->where('id',$_dividend_data['stock_id'])->value('short_name')}}</td>
                      <td>{{$_dividend_data['amount']}}</td>
                      <td>{{$_dividend_data['date']}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{'dividends'}}">Edit</a></td>
                      <td><a href="{{'#'}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` field as Primary key of your table.
First replace your **Laravel Blade Template Part** with below code::

```
@foreach($dividends_10 as $_dividend_data)
<tr>
  <td>{{Portfolio\StockModel::select('short_name')->where('id',$_dividend_data['stock_id'])->value('short_name')}}</td>
  <td>{{$_dividend_data['amount']}}</td>
  <td>{{$_dividend_data['date']}}</td>
  <td><a href="{{'dividends'}}">Edit</a></td>
  <td><a href="{{'#'}}" class="delete-mdoal" data-value="{{$_dividend_data['id']}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

After that use below **jQuery** to made *delete button* value dynamic:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on("click", ".delete-mdoal", function (e) {
        var delete_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $('button[name="delete_dividend"]').val(delete_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where to put the jquery code inside modal? <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete_dividend" value="foo">Delete</button> here here is the button code in modal

Comment: You need to put it in `<script>` tag

Comment: <script>
                        $(document).ready(function (e) {
                            $(document).on("click", ".delete-modal", function (e) {
                                var delete_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
                                $('button[name="delete_dividend"]').val(delete_id);
                            });
                        });
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete_dividend">Delete</button>
                    </script>